# How can I create a .htaccess file that 301 redirects to HTTPS, redirects trailing slash from end of URL to non and removes .php without conflicts?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been trying for hours now to create this .htaccess file without luck.

I have redeveloped my site and my SEO is a bit all over the place. For Google's and my users' sake, I need a .htaccess file that:

- Redirects `http://example.com/*` to `https://example.com/*`
- Redirects `*.example.com/*.php` to `https://example.com/*`
- Redirects `*.example.com/*/` to `https://example.com/*`

So to clarify, forces SSL, removes trailing slashes and .php extensions in a Google friendly (301-redirect) way. Or any combination of the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it - for all listed cases

```
Redirect permanent / https://secure.example.com/
```

Ref: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL